# to find invalid managers from a table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table :

xx_asg

```
person_no      location        org       mgr_person_no    effective_start_date               eff_end_date    
1               Mumbai        XYZ          101             01-jan-1901                       31-DEC-4712    
101             Delhi         xyz      201             01-JAN-2005                       31-DEC-4712    
5               Delhi         XYZ          1                01-JAN-1901                      31-DEC-4712
```

In this table each person has a manager whose person record is also ther in this table.

But as seen above there are cases like for `person no 1` with effective start date `01-jan-1901` but it has a manager person no. 101 
whose effective start date is from `01-jan-2005`. so this is invalid as from `1901-2005` this manager did not existed.

I want a query to get such cases from this table. Can anyone just guide through the logic

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join, and check if the manager dates is not in the person dates range, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(s.person_no = t.mgr_person_no)
WHERE s.effective_start_date > t.effective_start_date
   OR s.effective_end_date < t.effective_end_date
```

**EDIT:** If effective_start_date and effective_end_date columns are string and not dates, you have to convert them:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
INNER JOIN YourTable s
 ON(s.person_no = t.mgr_person_no)
WHERE to_date(s.effective_start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') > to_date(t.effective_start_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')
   OR to_date(s.effective_end_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') < to_date(t.effective_end_date,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Comment: @sagi- this isnt working... its not returning the above case.

Comment: @sreekembose Sry, typo.. mixed up t and s, will work now.

Comment: no @sagi this isnt working as well. not rturning any rows. Maybe because only one join is made in this.. ill try with inline view

Comment: Are you sure? Did you recopy my answer? made only a little change.

Comment: @sreekembose What types are effective_end/start_date ?>

Comment: Then you gave me wrong format, it seems suspicious because this query should work just fine on your example @sreekembose

Comment: I recreated the table and sagi's query works perfectly fine for me, after one correction: sreekem's last column is eff_end_date but sagi called it effective_end_date. (However, this should result in an error, not in "no rows returned.") The query needs some work though; for example it returns two person_no columns and two mgr_person_no columns. It should only keep the person_no column from s and only mgr_person_no from t. Sreekem: what do you mean by "not working"?